# How do I render the absolute URL of a referenced entity in a simplenews newsletter?

Tags: 8, theming, emails

When I send a node as a `simplenews` newsletter I use the node's `Email: HTML` display. 
One of the fields in this view is a `label` of a referenced entity to be rendered as a `Link to the referenced entity`.
Drupal renders it as a link with a relative / site-local URL. I want it to be rendered as an absolute / external URL.

For what it's worth:
In the render array the link is stored in
`$variable['items']['0']['content']['#url']` which is a `Drupal\Core\Url` with a protected `external` property of `false`

I can't see anything in the `Url` interface that would change `external` to `true` or indeed whether this is the thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`external` and `absolute` are different:

`external` is an url without internal route. You can't change this property. This is set when you create an url.

`absolute` is an option, which you can set at any time in the url object:

```
$url->setAbsolute();
```

Or set to false:

```
$url->setAbsolute(FALSE);
```

And this will change how the url is generated absolute or relative.

Comment: Totally brilliant, thanks.  I was expecting to find such a method in  the API documentation but it defeated me .... although I now have found it. I do feel we can do better with the API documentation .... not sure how.

Comment: could you provide said link iain?

Answer (score 2):

looks like that's a read-only property. Most other things can be changed with setOption() or specific methods. Not sure if that's an oversight or by design.

You need to build a new Url object object from the node object and pass the option in:

```
$node->toUrl('canonical', ['external' => TRUE]);
```